# Accessing information from another class

Tags: java, class

Currently I have this Class which is a basic Payroll report:

```
PayrollReport(Person person, double salary){
    this.person = person;
    this.salary = salary;
}

public String toString(){
    return person + " was paid "+ salary;
}
```

In a second class I press a button and it assigns values to the payroll class:

```
for (int i=0; i<;listOfPeople.size();i++){
    Person person = listOfPeople.get(i);
    double salary =listOfPeople.get(i).getSalary();
    newPayroll = new PayrollReportItem(person, salary);
}
```

I now want to display the PayrollReports toString() in a jTextFeild in a third class when a button is pressed.

After spending hours on this, all I have done was got the jTextFeild to display a rows of null.

Comment: Could you please share a small but complete executable code which you have tried at your end? It would help us to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are assigning values to the same object i.e. `newPayroll` again and again. So only the last value will be stored and rest all will be overwritten.

What you need to do  is this

1. When the button is pressed, make a new object of the second class.
2. Call a method in the second class that will create an object to the first class
3. Then assign value to it
4. Then call the `toString()` method
5. Repeat from step 2 till all values are printed.

Something like this

```
 Class Second{

    public void printAll(){
    for (int i=0; i<;listOfPeople.size();i++){
                    Person person = listOfPeople.get(i);
                    double salary =listOfPeople.get(i).getSalary();
             newPayroll = new PayrollReportItem(person, salary);
              newPayroll.toString();  //call method to print values 
                }
    }

Class Third{

   //when button pressed to the following
   Second obj=new Second();   //create an object of second class
  obj.printAll();   //call method to print 
}
```

Hope this helps :)